# Loading knockout bindings in jQuery Ajax Tabs

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-tabs

**Problem:** When using jQuery Tabs in AJAX mode, I load an .html file that has data-bindings on elements and at the bottom of the .html page. I declare my View Models and apply bindings. The bindings apply without errors, however, none of the data-binds are working.

```
$("#index-tabs").tabs('select', 3);
```

**So the flow is:**
Existing jQuery Tab Site -> Load ajax tab .html file with knockout bindings and apply bindings at the end -> all element bindings are not applied.

Anyone have an idea why this could be happening? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of you problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your `ko.applyBindings` call look like?  If your new html has a script at the end which creates your view model and calls `ko.applyBindings`, then it is trying to apply that new view model to the whole page.  There is a second parameter to applyBindings for the rootNode.  If you don't pass in an element, then it takes window.document.body as the root.  Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danbueno/6hRaQ/) for an example of applying two view models to two different elements.